# KDE application launcher shortcut ALT+F1 not working after reboot

Tags: shortcut-keys, launcher, kde

My problem is that in the Global Keyboard Shortcuts appear two application launcher widgets and the "wrong one" is set back to ALT+F1 after each reboot.

[Global Keyboard Shortcuts' image on my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeedL.png)

I exported the scheme and I identified the widgets id:

```
activate widget 101=none
activate widget 2=Alt+F1
```

The wrong one is the number 2 when I changed 101 to this:

```
activate widget 101=Alt+F1
activate widget 2=none
```

Everything works, but I have to do that after every single reboot.

How I can leave only the working widget and delete the wrong widget?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am on OpenSUSE 42.3 but found the following: I had to edit `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc` in addition to `~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc`. You will look for the widget number you want to delete (Widget 56 in my case), and then delete the referenced to that number (picture attached). In my case, I had to delete the entire [containments] section that the launcher was in (`[Containments][21]` in the picture), due to a panel that disappeared during a driver upgrade.

[image: Screenshot of Application Launcher section]

After that, I deleted the reference to the shortcut in `~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc`, then logged out. When I logged back in, I was able to set the shortcut as I wanted.

Comment: I'm using KDE neon 5.11, I did everything as instructed, same file locations and application launcher is now working, this answer took months of frustration away, thank you very much!

Comment: This is still an issue it seems. Even on Ubuntu 19.04 after two years. Did some report this as a bug?

Comment: Seems like the issue found it's way into Ubuntu 20.04. My solution was to remove all shortcut sections containing `Alt+F1` from `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`. I didn't edit `~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc`. After login out and back in, i could set the shortcut without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may modify the shortcut key directly in `~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc` configuration file:

```
$ cat ~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc | grep 'Activate Application Launcher Widget$'
activate widget 101=none,none,Activate Application Launcher Widget
activate widget 2=Alt+F1,none,Activate Application Launcher Widget
```

After modifying you should have something like this:

```
$ cat ~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc | grep 'Activate Application Launcher Widget$'
activate widget 101=Alt+F1,none,Activate Application Launcher Widget
activate widget 2=none,none,Activate Application Launcher Widget
```

Then re-login.

Comment: I did it, but, after the reboot, it return to the previous values:

    $ cat ~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc | grep 'Activate Application Launcher Widget$'
    activate widget 101=,none,Activate Application Launcher Widget
    activate widget 2=Alt+F1,none,Activate Application Launcher Widget

Comment: Maybe change configuration file when not using KDE? So that it does not overwrite settings e.g. during logout etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Right-click** on the **Start** button, select "**Configure Application Launcher...**", **Keyboard Shortcuts**, assign it to **Alt+F1**.

[image: Application Launcher Settings - Plasma Keyboard Shortcuts]

---

Editing **`.config/kglobalshortcutsrc`** manually no longer works because there can be multiple application launcher widgets, one for each display (even if no longer connected), assigned randomly.